# Where can I define a class globally?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a class, and I'd like to make it available for use anywhere within a Flash project. Where should I put it? Ideally, it'd be in a separate ActionScript file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your ActionScript 3 project using classes, you can simply create global variable using public static like this :

```
//MyClass.as
package {
 public class MyClass {
  public static var myValue = 3;
 }
}

//Arbitrary.as
package {
 public class Arbitrary {
  function Arbitrary():void {
   trace(MyClass.myValue); //3
  }
 }
}
```

You in every project, follow these steps to enable.

Click ActionScript 3.0 Settings...
[image]
Click Source path folder icon, select a you want src folders.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Haha, nothing quite so complicated :) I'm just wondering where I should even put this code. (New to Flash, mostly!)

Comment: Answer modification.Please check.

Answer (score -1):

You can use top level default package declaration.

```
package com.abc.globals
{
    //Note here No Class Declaration

    public var globalVars:String = "Global is horrible";
}
```

So that you can use `without import statement` and you can use access variable `without class or instance`.

It is like our `trace("Hello Global")`.

`globalVars` will access from anywhere in application.

Comment: Okay, but that's not what I meant. See the 2-hours-previous accepted answer.

Comment: @minitech i saw your accepts answer that right and it may also useful at somepoint.